# How large is a thimble of brandy?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

How large is a thimble of brandy? The size of the thumb?

The definition from New Oxford American Dictionary seems irrelevant:

> n. a metal or plastic cap with a closed end, worn to protect the finger and push the needle in sewing.  SPECIAL USAGE:  a short metal tube or ferrule.

I see it being used for much larger things, e.g. [here](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/465418942739146347/)

> At £11 for a thimble of whisky, who in their right mind uses a hotel minibar

and [here](https://twitter.com/ClarkBosch/status/380399836119326720/photo/1).

Comment: Where did you see the phrase "a thimble of brandy"? Please include more context.

Comment: Here's the definition from Oxford American Dictionary: n. a metal or plastic cap with a closed end, worn to protect the finger and push the needle in sewing.    a short metal tube or ferrule.

Comment: That is exactly the definition.  Now imagine one of those filled with brandy.  The meaning is completly literal.

Comment: You're being misled by the photo  of a normal-sized tumbler glass of whisky that accompanies the first quote. The thimble is shaped like a tiny cup or goblet, if anything is thimble-sized it means it's tiny.

Comment: @JamesK, I think that the usage of thimble relating to quantity of liquids is rarely literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thimble is a tiny metal cup that is placed over a finger when sewing: they come in different sizes, depending on the size of your finger, but typically have a capacity of 2-5 ml. When used to describe liquids, it means a very very small, probably insufficient, amount of liquid.

Your first link describes the miniature bottles of spirits found in hotel minibars- typically 20 to 50ml. In the UK, a single measure of whisky is 25 ml, so a 20ml bottle is a bit small, though a 50ml bottle contains a double measure. The usage of **thimble** is not literal, but is intended to suggest that there is not enough whisky in one miniature. The associated photograph is intended to show what the writer thinks a *proper* glass of whisky should look like, not what a thimble of whisky looks like.

Your second link shows a photo of cup of soup: most people would assume that a cup of soup would be at least teacup size (150-200ml), but the cup in the photo is an espresso cup, about 50ml. The writer refers to it as a thimble: again, this is not literal, but is simply intended to suggest that the cup is too small.

Comment: FWIW, some thimble pix: https://tinyurl.com/yymsqfza